# How do I write to addresses with offsets?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making an external hack code but I can't(don't know) how to write to a addresses 
EX:0x0471604 
that has an offset of 0x14
If anyone could be so kind as to teach me I would be ecstatic
here's a sample of my code  so Y'all can maybe point out where I went wrong:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstring>

 #include <Windows.h>

 DWORD Ammo = 0x028FA348;
 DWORD AmmoOffsets[] = {0x348,0x14,0x0};
 DWORD PointedAmmo;
 int ModdedAmmo = 1000;

 void AmmoMod()
 {
      HANDLE ProccessHandle = 
      OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GameProcessID);
      ReadProcessMemory(ProccessHandle, (LPCVOID)(Ammo + AmmoOffsets), &PointedAmmo, sizeof(PointedAmmo), 0);
      WriteProcessMemory(ProccessHandle, (LPCVOID)PointedAmmo, &ModdedAmmo, sizeof(ModdedAmmo), 0);
 }
```

Comment: Address 0x100. If I add an offset of 0x5 to this address, what is the resulting address?

Comment: MPops did anyone answer the question cause if they did could you maybe link it.

Comment: An offset is just a value added to the original address. Like; if the original address is 100 and the offset is 42, the resulting address is 142. What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: @MassimoDiStasi Unfortunately, I'm not gonna use up more of my time to look for that. However, have you given thought to the question I gave you? If you can answer that, I'm sure you will be able to solve this larger problem yourself! You can do it! :)

Comment: @MPops than just close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: Looks like a similar problem has been asked for over the years.  Something in [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AmmoOffsets) might help you.

Comment: Hacking other processes memory is not a trivial task. Even if you get the math right, you may still be looking in the wrong spot. Programs (and operating systems) that want to make these sorts of tricks harder move things around. A hard coded offset may only be valid once in a blue moon.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint32_t address = /*some value*/;
uint32_t offset = /*some value*/;
uint32_t final_address = address + offset;
uint32_t result = *(uint32_t*) final_address;
```

This is technically how you access an "address" with an "offset". Granted, this will likely give you a seg fault 99% of the time, but this is a way to do it.

Comment: Eeek. C style cast.

Comment: Not useful with ReadProcessMemory

Answer (score 0):

To get the final address of your pointer chain, the address of the ammo variable you can use this function, then just call WriteProcessMemory on ammoAddr.

```cpp
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}

uintptr_t ammoAddr = FindDMAAddy(hProcess, dynamicPtrBaseAddr, { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 });

WriteProcessMemory(ProccessHandle, (LPCVOID)ammoAddr, &ModdedAmmo, sizeof(ModdedAmmo), 0);
```